# request.auth.isAuthenticated is false for 'try' or 'optional' auth modes

Tags: hapi.js

Referring to this [lib/auth.js](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/auth.js#L205) if my handler uses a *try* or *optional* strategy the **isAuthenticated** is false, even though the user is logged in and has a active session.

This is a bummer because I have a **onPreResponse** handler which adds the user credentials to the view context, which is used by the template to show a login or a logout link.

The onPreResponse code is exactly like [hapi-context-credentials](https://github.com/mtharrison/hapi-context-credentials)

The template looks like this (snippet):

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>{{#if credentials.username}}
                     <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                 {{else}}
                     <a href="/login">Login</a>
                 {{/if}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

***edit: Adding example source code***

This is the example code from [hapi-context-credentials](https://github.com/mtharrison/hapi-context-credentials/tree/master/examples/basic) modified to remove **auth** config from one of the routes. To test:

1. Navigate to http://localhost:4000/hbs and login (john:secret)
2. You are greeted with **Hello John!**
3. Then navigate to http://localhost:4000/jade, you are greeted with **Hello guest!** even though you have just logged in

**index.js**

```
    var Hapi = require('hapi');
    var Path = require('path');

    var server = new Hapi.Server();
    server.connection({ port: 4000 });

    server.views({
        engines: {
            hbs: require('handlebars'),
            jade: require('jade')
        },
        path: __dirname,
        isCached: false
    });

    server.register([
        {
            register: require('hapi-context-credentials'),// hapi-context-credentials
        }, {
            register: require('hapi-auth-basic')
        }
    ], function (err) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        var validateFunc = function (username, password, callback) {

            // Just authenticate everyone and store username
            // in credentials

            if (username === 'john' && password === 'secret') {
                return callback(null, true, {username: 'john'});    
            }

            return callback(null, false, {});
        };

        server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', {
            validateFunc: validateFunc
        });

        server.route([{
                config: {
                    auth: {
                        strategy: 'simple',
                        mode: 'required'
                    }
                },
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/hbs',
                handler: function(request, reply) {

                    reply.view('example.hbs');          // Handlebars example
                }
            }, {

                method: 'GET',
                path: '/jade',
                handler: function(request, reply) {

                    reply.view('example.jade');         // Jade example
                }
            }
        ]);

        server.start(function() {
            console.log('Started server: ' + server.info.uri);
        });
    });
```

**example.hbs**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{#if credentials}}
        <h1>Hello {{credentials.username}}!</h1>
        {{else}}
        <h1>Hello guest!</h1>
        {{/if}}
    </body>
    </html>
```

**example.jade**

```
        doctype html
    html(lang="en")
      head
        title= Example
      body
        if credentials
          h1 Hello #{credentials.username}!
        else
          h1 Hello guest!
```

*Note*: you need these npm modules:

- hapi
- handlebars
- jade
- hapi-auth-basic
- hapi-context-credentials

Comment: It's only `false` if all strategies are exhuasted and none of them authenticate the user. If your user is logged in though, that shouldn't happen? One of them (cookie?) should work.

Comment: If you're still struggling, I think we'll need more code to help.

Comment: updated my question with sample code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you need to pass some context in when you do `reply.view`?

Answer (score 2):

In the example code you posted, your `/jade` route doesn't have any authentication set on it, therefore hapi doesn't have access to your credentials for the corresponding view. As HTTP is a stateless protocol these aren't just "remembered" by the server between requests, you need to identify yourself for every request.

If you want to be able to log in once and then have credentials available across multiple requests you either need to do one of the following:

1. Continue to use basic auth but set the `auth` config property on **EVERY** route. You don't need to login every page because your browser will remember credentials and send the `Authorization` header.
2. Use hapi-auth-cookie to store credentials in session. You still need to set `auth` property on **EVERY** route that you want to access those credentials.
3. Use something like [Yar](https://github.com/hapijs/yar) to store credentials in session and then retrieve them using `request.session.get()`

One thing you have brought to my attention is that I need to update hapi-context-credentials for hapi 9.x.x and hapi-auth-basic 3.x.x, so thanks for that.

Comment: In my hapijs app I already use hapi-auth-cookie and I see the same behaviour when there is no authentication (even though the session cookie is set on each request). I'll try the Yar plugin.

Comment: What do you mean by "see the same behaviour when there is no authentication"? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: It took a while to wrap my head around this. Thanks for clearing this up. Essentially I had to unset the **redirectTo** in *server.auth.strategy* options *and* set 
    auth: {
        mode: 'try',
        strategy: 'session'
    },

for each of the routes's auth.